# Merge padas rows if the difference between consecutive rows are less than two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1     col2         col3
 A       [p,s]         2
 A       [q]           3
 A       [r,t]         4
 A       [p,x]         7
 B       [x,y]         8
 C       [s]           4
 C       [t,v]         6
 C       [u,x]         7
```

the df is sorted by col1. Now for each col1 values of the previous or/and next row if difference between consecutive col3 values are less than 2 then merge col2 values in a single row. So the data frame would look like,

```
df
col1    col2
 A      [p,s,q,r,t]
 A      [p,x]
 B      [x,y]
 C      [s]
 C      [t,v,u,x]
```

This could be done using for loop by filtering col1 values each time but it will take more time to execute, looking for some pandas shortcuts to do it most efficiently.

Comment: edited the question, if the difference between consecutive col3 values are less than 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create groups by compared if differency is greater of equal 2 with cumulative sums first:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('col1')['col3'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().ge(2).cumsum())
```

And then use column for aggregate with flatten list of lists in lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
df = df.groupby(['col1','g'])['col2'].agg(f).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
  col1             col2
0    A  [p, s, q, r, t]
1    A           [p, x]
2    B           [x, y]
3    C              [s]
4    C     [t, v, u, x]
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `diff` calculate the difference, the after `cumsum` take the groups and get the list.

```py
d = [[ 'A',       ['p','s'] ,        2],
[ 'A',       ['q']   ,        3],
[ 'A',       ['r','t'] ,        4],
[ 'A',       ['p','x'] ,        7],
[ 'B',       ['x','y'] ,        8],
[ 'C',       ['s']   ,        4],
[ 'C',       ['t','v'] ,        6],
[ 'C',       ['u','x'] ,        7]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])


df['diff'] = df['col3'].diff().abs().fillna(0)
df.loc[df['diff']<2, ['diff']] = 0
df.loc[df['diff']>=2, ['diff']] = 1

df['diff'] = df['diff'].cumsum()

df_out = df.groupby(['col1', 'diff']).apply(lambda x: [j for i in x['col2'] for j in i]).reset_index()
df_out.drop(columns=['diff'], inplace=True)

print(df_out)
```

```
 col1                0
0    A  [p, s, q, r, t]
1    A           [p, x]
2    B           [x, y]
3    C              [s]
4    C     [t, v, u, x]
```